# How do I delete Azure Databricks workspace via script

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

Is posible to delete An Azure Databricks workspace via Script. I´m trying to build my resources via script with ARM, and also i´m doing the same with resource deletion with powershell scripting.

I could´n find the powershell command to delete a databricks workspace, like others :

[Remove-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/remove-azurermnetworksecuritygroup?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

[Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetwork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/remove-azurermvirtualnetwork?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

[Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Are there any alternatives to delete resources via scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to delete a resource in powershell, use this command

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ResourceName $DatabricksWorkspaceName -ResourceType Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces -Force
```

where:

$ResourceGroup is the resource group where your databricks resource is.

$DatabricksWorkspaceName is the name of your databricks resource.

Also You can use to delete other types of resources adapting the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure Databricks offers only [REST API](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/index.html).

You may use the below REST API to delete the workspace.

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/{workspaceName}?api-version=2018-04-01
```

[image]

**Note:** If it returns 202, the workspace will be deleted soon.

For more details, refer [Azure Databricks Workspaces- Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/delete).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in powershell to delete the workspace, if you want to do that via powershell script, the workaround is to call the rest api: [`Workspaces - Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/delete) via powershell.

**Sample:**

```
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/{workspaceName}?api-version=2018-04-01"
$accesstoken = "eyJ0eXAixxxxxxh5Elu0MC0w"
$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
}

Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method DELETE
```

[image]

To get the `$accesstoken` in the command above, the easiest way is to click the `Try it` button in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/delete#code-try-0), login and copy the token.

[image]

If you don't want this way, you can also use azure ad [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to generate the access token. Here is a [sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2017/06/28/using-powershell-as-an-azure-arm-rest-api-client/), you could refer to it. Don't forget to change the `$ARMResource` to `https://management.azure.com/`.

[image]